# Google Play: Some Samsung Galaxy S5 models excluded while others are supported

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, android-manifest

We are developing an Android App with Xamarin and want to publish on Google Play. As a requirement we have to support a limited set of devices based on their screen size and density.

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Our minimum SDK version is 15. There are no additional requirements added.

After uploading the App as an Alpha version, Google Play shows about 15 Galaxy S5s as supported devices while 3 are not. See the images.

[image: Supported S5s]
[image: Unsupported S5s]

Wanting to target as many devices as possible within our limits we would like to understand why 3 of these model codes are excluded while the majority is not. Did anyone have a similiar experience?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:screenDensity="640".

There are some devices with very high pixel density, but I'm not sure  whether it is your case.